# ByRef argument type mismatch error

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to call a routine named `VBCopyFolder` using string variables, but get a *"ByRef argument type mismatch"* error referencing `strOldPath` when doing so.  I'm a bit lost as how to do this.

VBCopyFolder is defined as:

```
VBCopyFolder(ByRef strSource As String, ByRef strTarget As String)
```

and the call that I'm trying to make is:

```
Dim strOldPath, strNewPath As String
Call VBCopyFolder(strOldPath, strNewPath)
```

The following works fine:

```
Call VBCopyFolder("U:\Database\Data.accdb", "Z:\Backups\Data.accdb")
```

How do I correctly format this call?

Comment: Try `Dim strOldPath As String, strNewPath As String`

Comment: That was it!  I knew that it was something stupid that I was overlooking.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

In VBA,

```vbs
Dim strOldPath, strNewPath As String
```

is equivalent to

```vbs
Dim strOldPath As Variant, strNewPath As String
```

If you want both variables to be of type `String` you need to use

```vbs
Dim strOldPath As String, strNewPath As String
```